# Setting label text in another class

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

In my viewcontroller,
I am creating a label here.

In another viewcontroller I am creating an instance of the first view controller. Here I tried setting the text property of the label. But it doesn't work. I have checked my code over and over and couldn't find any anything missing.
I tried creating the label both programmatically as well as using interface builder. Still cant set the text property of the label. Any reason for this?

I create the label in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[myLabel setText:@"Hi"];
[myLabel1 setText:@"Hello"];
 [myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(105, 130, 120, 30)];
 [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 [myLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
 [myLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
 [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
 [myLabel release];
}
```

In my first view controller

```
MySecondViewcontroller *showMyViewcontroller = [[ MySecondViewcontroller    alloc]initWithNibName:@"MySecondViewcontroller" bundle:nil];;
showMyViewcontroller.myLabel = @"I cant set the text";
[self.navigationcontroller pushViewController: showMyViewcontroller animated:YES];
[showMyViewcontroller release];
```

What I am doing wrong here

Comment: How are you declaring it and accessing it from the other class? A bit of code never hurts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an intermediate string to do it, like so:

In FirstViewController:

```
- (void)loadNextView {
    // load your view
    SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    // set a string in your second view (NOT a label)
    vc.myString = @"Some String";

    // push it or whatever
    [self.navigaitonController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

In your SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *myLabel;
    NSString *myString;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
```

In your SecondViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // view is now loaded, so we can set the label:
    myLabel.text = myString;
}
```

Comment: Edit: myString.text to just myString

Answer (score 0):

You try to assign a string to a UILabel, you'll need to assign the string to myLabel.text. Also you'll have to make sure the UILabel is accessible, so make sure it's a property.